# How to disable Disable the stock Linux NFS server?

Tags: centos, nfs

I need to install MAPR on three node cluster and it is asking to Disable the stock Linux NFS server on nodes that will run the MapR NFS server.

i have found one help on internet and it says to Start / Stop / Restart NFS Service under RHEL / CentOS Linux use below command

```
/etc/init.d/nfs stop
```

I just wanted to know if this is the correct way to do that.

Comment: No, it is not. Read the [official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/).

Answer (score 0):

> chkconfig nfs off

So it doesn't start on boot.

Comment: A command is not enough, explain what it does and how. It doesn't need to be long but it is required.